# method call problem with Python

Tags: python, object, methods, attributes, python-idle

So I'm learning python, and I seem to be having a consistent problem with calling `setText()` methods on `Text` objects. The process works fine when I'm in the interactive IDLE GUI, but when I save modules and then try to run them, I get:

> `nonetype` object has no attribute `setText`

Do I need to assign some sort of return type to the text assignment? Why would there be different behavior from IDLE to saved modules? I've searched the site and Python documentation and was unable to turn up anything. Any help would be much appreciated.

```
message1 = Text(Point(50,50), "Click).draw(win)
message1.setText("")
```

<sub>*Edited to add…*</sub>

Thanks Geo, your suggestion fixed things.

Now my question is, what's the difference between...

```
message = Text(Point(50,50), "Click").draw(win)
```

… and …

```
message = Text(Point(50,50), "Click")
message.draw(win)
```

… with regards to returning something, or ensuring that the `message` object has a `type` that supports certain functions?

Comment: Show the definition of `draw` (if it looks like I must assume now, the code will fail in IDLE as well, so:) and check again if the code that runs in IDLE is really 100% identical. If not, show it as well.

Comment: message1 = Text(Point(50,50), "Click).draw(win)

You forgot an apostrophe. Maybe it's the problem?

Comment: @utdmr: That would be a syntax error.

Comment: the first one is instantiating an object, it calls draw on it, and stores the result of the draw method in the message variable. The second one stores the `result of the constructor`, if I can say it like this, and calls the method draw on it. Since the object is an instance of `Text`, this is supported. As far as I can tell, the `draw` method doesn't return anything, so `message` will be set to `None`. This is why you're experiencing this behaviour.

Comment: Ok, I see. That makes perfect sense. Thanks Geo and Communist Duck.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not sure how to answer your second question properly..so I'll just do it as an answer here.

The reason the first does not work is because you are assigning the return value of Text.draw to message. Since it returns nothing, then message is `None`.

In the working code, you assign message with the type `Text` and initialize the object. You then call the `draw` method of this object, and the `setText` method.

In the non-working code, you are calling the `draw` method on a new `Text` object, then assigning the return of that - that is, NoneType - to message. And since `None` has no setText method, you get an error.

(Sorry if I have mixed up NoneType and None there)

Answer (score 2):

Perhaps the `draw` method is not returning anything. Try changing your code to this:

```
message1 = Text(Point(50,50), "Click")
message1.draw(win)
message1.setText("")
```